# How does $\frac{-1}{2(i+1)} = \frac{-(1-i)}{4}$?

Tags: complex-numbers

[image]

How did $\frac{-1}{2(i+1)}$ change to $\frac{-(1-i)}{4}$??

Comment: $$ - \frac{1}{2(1+i)} \ \ = \ \ - \frac{1 - i}{2(1+i)(1-i)} \ \ = \ \ -\frac{1-i}{2 · 2} \ \ . $$  The numerator and denominator are multiplied by the complex conjugate of $ \ 1 + i \ . $

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please, if possible, use MathJax to format out your doubt or your question.

Answer (score 2):

Multiply it by $\frac{i-1}{i-1}$.

Comment: the OP might ask "why?". You should add that we multiply it by the "conjugate" of the denominator